# What does local caching for android In-app Billing do?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Curious... In the documentation for Android In-app Billing v3, it says:

> Because the Google Play client now caches In-app Billing information
>   locally on the device, you can use the Version 3 API to query for this
>   information more frequently, for example through a getPurchases call.
>   Unlike with previous versions of the API, many Version 3 API calls
>   will be serviced through cache lookups instead of through a network
>   connection to Google Play, which significantly speeds up the API's
>   response time.

What does this mean, or in what ways will this help me? Should I not bother with storing SharedPreferences for when a user is without a network connection? Do I need to do anything special to implement this (access cache)?

Answer (score 0):

What this does is allows you to make more frequent calls to update your inventory. As the V3 documentation also notes, the previous call had to hit the network which made it more expensive and meant that developers were discouraged from using it as frequently. Now, because of the local cache that is not the case.

The downside I have seen is that the local cache is not always up to date and there appears to be no quick way to force it to sync other than restarting your device or clearing the Google Play cache.

Comment: I am wondering with this caching, do we still need to keep our own status if something is bought in SharedPreferences or can we query based on sku on the fly using google api?